# Como ler dados com variáveis nas linhas, no RStudio?

Tags: data, r

Estou começando com a linguagem R no Rstudio. Sou usuário avançado de MATLAB mas com dificuldades no R.

Minha pergunta é: Tenho uma planilha onde cada linha é uma variável e cada coluna é uma observação na série temporal. Gostaria de saber se há como dentro do RStudio ele importar sem fazer a sua leitura usual (cada coluna é uma variável e cada linha é uma observação)?

Comment: Você pode ler a planilha, e depois usar a função `t` (transpose) para converter de linhas para colunas.

Answer (score 2):

Se quando você diz "no RStudio" se refere à opção via o menu (Tools > Import Dataset), não é possível. Este menu apenas cria um snippet para ler os dados, de acordo com os parâmetros que você configurar.

Como o @carlosfigueira mencionou, o que você precisa é da função de transposição, `t()`. Depois de lido basta ter cuidado apenas com os nomes das colunas e o tipo de objeto.

Você vai ter que ler com `header = FALSE`, e então fazer algumas modificações no data.frame lido para deixá-lo na forma correta. Recomendo também usar `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Por exemplo, considerando que você salvou a planilha em csv a partir do MS Excel em português:

```
csvtext <- "Var1;1,2;1,5;1,6
            Var2;2;4;6
            Var3;7;8;9,2"

dat1 <- read.csv2(text = csvtext, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Você usaria read.csv2(file = "pasta/arquivo.csv", ...)
dat2 <- t(dat1[, -1])    
dat3 <- as.data.frame(dat2)

rownames(dat3) <- NULL
colnames(dat3) <- dat1[, 1]

dat3
#  Var1             Var2             Var3
#  1.2                2              7.0
#  1.5                4              8.0
#  1.6                6              9.2

str(dat3)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Var1            : num  1.2 1.5 1.6
# $             Var2: num  2 4 6
# $             Var3: num  7 8 9.2
```

Apesar de ser recomendo fortemente mudar a forma de aquisição dos dados, se for possível. Esta organização não é padrão "do R", é a mais comum em organização de dados.

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal! Ajudou bastante!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a transpostas dos dados de entrada:

```
mdat <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 11,12,13), nrow = 2, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE,
               dimnames = list(c("row1", "row2"),
                               c("C.1", "C.2", "C.3")))

dim(mdat)
str(mdat)

mdat2 <- t(mdat)
dim(mdat2)
str(mdat2)
```